# Regex define two lists of allowed characters/digits

Tags: java, javascript, regex, validation, logic

I'm working on a phone number regex and this is what I have so far: `^[0-9~+ ]{8,20}$`

It allows digits between 0 and 9, and '+' and whitespace are allowed as well. The range has to be somewhere between 8 and 20. This works fine.

What I want further is to have 8 to 20 of digits only, where '+' and whitespace come separate from them.

Something like this:  `^[+ ]\d{8,20}$`

Suggestions?

Comment: What is wrong with your `^[+ ]\d{8,20}$` approach?

Comment: Do you mean whitespace can be anywhere or just preceding the digits?

Comment: @gtgaxiola  Anywhere. Could be used to split up the digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
^(?:[+ ]*\d){8,20}$
```

This will match from 8 to 20 digits preceded or not by `+` or space.

If the `+` can be only at the beginig:

```
^[+]?(?:[ ]*\d){8,20}$
```

Comment: I would move out the `+` outside otherwise it will match on `+  123  123 + 123`.   Something like : `^\+?(?:[\s]*\d){8,20}$`.

Comment: @gtgaxiola: May be, But the requierment isn't so clear about that. Nevertheless, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Got it... Forgot you don't have to escape when using the brackets `[+]`

Comment: Great :) I will test it on monday